# composable cannot exceed 13 under compsoe NavHost

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(navController: NavHostController) {
    val actions = Actions(navController)
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = Routes.SplashPage) {
        composable(Routes.SetPage) { SetPage(actions) }
        composable(Routes.AboutPage) { AboutPage(actions) }
        composable(Routes.FeedBackPage) { FeedBackPage(actions) }
        composable(Routes.WebViewPage + "{url}") { WebViewPage(actions, url = "") }
        composable(Routes.UserPage) { UserPage(actions) }
        composable(Routes.EditPage + "/{title}/{content}") { EditPage(actions) }
        composable(Routes.PwdSetPage + "{type}") { PwdSetPage(actions) }
        composable(Routes.QrCodePage) { QrCodePage(actions) }
        composable(Routes.SplashPage) { SplashPage(actions) }
        composable(Routes.MainPage) { MainPage(actions) }
        composable(Routes.SearchPage) { SearchPage(actions) }
        composable(Routes.ProListPage) { ProListPage(actions) }
        composable(Routes.ProDetailPage + "{data}")) { ProDetailPage(actions) }
    }
}
```

// error info
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication01, PID: 24926
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=13; index=13
at androidx.collection.SparseArrayCompat.valueAt(SparseArrayCompat.java:379)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:948)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:95)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:109)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(Unknown Source:13)
at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:140)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2156)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2422)
at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:83)
at com.example.myapplication01.ui.theme.ThemeKt.MyApplicationTheme(Theme.kt:41)
at com.example.myapplication01.ui.theme.ThemeKt$MyApplicationTheme$1.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
at com.example.myapplication01.ui.theme.ThemeKt$MyApplicationTheme$1.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:140)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2156)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2422)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:227)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:148)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:113)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:106)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$4.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$4.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:140)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2156)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2399)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2580)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2573)
at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotState.kt:540)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2566)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2542)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:613)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:764)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:103)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:447)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:416)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1055)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:875)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:772)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1042)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24926 SIG: 9

Comment: please add the code of composable which causes the issue

Comment: [code img][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7ke8.jpg

Comment: If you wanna your question to be answered fast, you wanna make time for an expert to get working sample with reproducible problem as fast as possible. Perfectly I should just paste your code into my sample project and see the problem as fast as I run it. In you case the problem is clearly somewhere where I can't see it. Try to find which exactly user action triggers this crash. Add prints on each place you're using `navController`

Comment: Normally add more than 13 pages to the compose application, and an error will be reported when the run command is executed, and there is no other operation

Comment: github address: link](https://github.com/gang2Android/testcompose)

Comment: I'm not gonna download your project, sorry. You need to try removing your destinations one by one to localize your problem and when you have just a couple of composables which I can paste to my project I'll take a look

Answer (score 2):

Seems to have been a bug in the library, ran into the same issue.

Fixed on the latest version of navigation:

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha08"
```